# software to automaticaly closes applications after certain time

Tags: windows-7, parental-control

I am looking for a software (probably some parental control type software?) that will run on a computer and is able to close running applications after certain hour and also restrict access during certain time.

For example: Thunderbird: allow to run it only monday to friday from 6am to 3pm. If the application is opened after 3pm, automatically close it.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Willing to spend some money for it?

**HomeGuard Activity Monitor** seems to do what you want and a whole lot more, for $50, http://veridium.net/homeguard-activity-monitor/program-blocker/

For somewhat cheaper, $35, **Time Boss** seems great http://nicekit.com/parental-control-software.htm

One free one I did find is **Romaco Timeout** https://romacocanada.ca/timeout/, you can check it out, but to me it didn't seem as robust, and also it is officially discontinued.